# Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed in sqlserver 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

i want to delete a particular log file from database, below is the query

```
delete from fn_dblog(null,null) where [Begin Time] like '2018%'
```

but i get an error "Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed".

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2875/how-to-allow-ad-hoc-updates-in-sql-server-system-catalogs/

Comment: I am getting this error "The configuration option 'database mail XPs' does not exist, or it may be an advanced option."

Comment: EXEC sp_configure 'database mail XPs', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;
GO

Comment: Or right click on sql server database in SSMS select facets slect surface area from facet dropdown  you will find this option there as well just select true.

Comment: i tried "EXEC sp_configure 'database mail XPs', 1; GO RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE; GO" but getting this error, "The configuration option 'database mail XPs' does not exist, or it may be an advanced option."

Answer (score 1):

```
sp_configure 'allow updates' ,0;

reconfigure with override;
```

[from here](http://saurabhsinhainblogs.blogspot.in/2015/05/Ad-hoc-update-to-system-catalog-is-not-supported-spconfigure-allow-updates.html)

and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39195855/6186890)

Comment: i tried "EXEC sp_configure 'database mail XPs', 1; GO RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE; GO" but getting this error, "The configuration option 'database mail XPs' does not exist, or it may be an advanced option."

Comment: please try this first: EXEC sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options', 1

RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE

go
And then my answer

Answer (score 1):

---- First run below script

```
EXEC sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options', 1

RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE

go

------ then run below script

EXEC sp_configure ‘Database Mail XPs’,1

GO

RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE

GO
```